# How to align the actionscript project?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a pure code Actionscript 3 project in flash builder 4 and I want to align the stage.
For now I have a sprite that I have set the x property to 10, but the sprites are in the middle of the screen. How to set these kind of properties in code? I suppose it's the stage object that needs to be set in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Stage.align](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#align) property.
For example, if you want to align your Stage depending the top left corner :

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Make sure the stage is available though...